# How to add a container dependency to Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins pipeline as my ci/cd tool with jenkinsfile included in source code.
In one of my stages which uses agent docker for example PHP, I run all tests there. Everything is fine so far.
But sometimes I need to inject other containers for example a MySQL instance to run all tests against a real database as an assurance. So I really searched the Internet and I could not find anything relevant. How do you resolve dependencies in docker pipeline?
Consider that these 2 containers (PHP and MySQL) must be in the same network.

```
stage('Build and test') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'php:7.3'
                }
            }
            steps {

                sh 'composer install'

                sh './vendor/bin/phpunit'
            }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using declarative pipeline much yet. You could probably get to it using a [parallel](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel) block, however its a little complex imho. I would rather go with a sequential step that runs outside of an image and run the db image manually with a `sh` step, then do the docker block, then cleanup.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not what i want. i am looking for a standard way to do such things in declarative pipeline.tnx anyway

Comment: To expand on the issue: The `docker` directive will start the image, run the steps inside it and clean it up. I did not find any standard way in form of some directive, i guess standard way is to spin it up just on the shell and stop it after your tests ran, i.e. not inside some docker directivy.

Comment: tnx i will give it try.